# Как правильно отлавливать ширину экрана и показывать правильную версию сайта (мобилка, десктоп)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, reactjs

Всем привет, уважаемые программисты! За ответы заранее благодарен.

Например я хочу сделать отдельно 2 версии сайта. Не хочу использовать резиновую верстку, так как некоторые модули необходимо кардинально переделывать под мобилку))

1. для ПК и Планшетов.
2. для мобилок. Урезанные данные и тд.

**Как мне правильно отлавливать кому какой сайт показывать?**

Например хочу сделать как на яндекс маркете.

- я захожу с ПК (показывается для ПК и планшетов),
- нажимаю F12 консоль + нажимаю мобилка (значок) + перезагружаю страницу (появляется мобильная версия)
- при изменении ширины версия сайта не меняется

Comment: Что на счет использования Bootstrap? В этом фреймворке есть готовые инструменты для адаптивной верстки.

Comment: @Paganini, автор же написал, что ему нужны именно отдельные версии, а не адаптивный сайт

Comment: Можете попробовать [этот вариант](https://vk-book.ru/opredelenie-mobilnogo-ustrojstva-v-php/)

Comment: Такое отлавиливать желаетльно на бэкэнде на фронтэнде будет все прыгать. Если на бэкэнде отлавить то тогда css и js файлы желательно загружать только для мобильных устройств, они на много меньше получатся, подключить webp еще и будет щастье

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
header('Location: http://m.mysite.com' , true, 301);
```

для планшетов необходимо показывать ПК версию с минимальной адаптивкой, для этого Юзер_Агент должен отловить Андройд без Мобаил

Answer (score -1):

Всё обычно обходится через css ,а именно media запросы, а раньше такой адаптивной вёрстки не было и поэтому использовались поддомены , то есть брали и переписывали верстку под мобильное устройство и ПК.
Вот яркий пример этого

https://vk.com

https://m.vk.com

Код ниже означает , что если ширина экрана будет меньше чем 900px то к aritcle будет применён padding 10px 3px ,а иначе его вовсе не будет

```
article{
   padding: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  article {
    padding: 10px 3px;
  }
}
```

Так же через media запросы можно проверить ориентацию экрана

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Можете прочитать тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Если у вас есть javascript код который невозможно адаптировать через media css, то вы можете воспользоваться событиями из javascript

Вот к примеру отслеживает изменение размера окна

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeFoo);
function resizeFoo(){
   console.log(window.outerWidth , window.outerHeight);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

А это изменение ориентации экрана

```
screen.addEventListener("orientationchange", function () {
  console.log("Ориентация экрана: " + screen.orientation);
});
```

Comment: Вы вопрос внимательно прочитали? Автору нужны как раз разные версии, а не одна адаптивная.